# What counts as a pipeline?

Tags: computer-architecture

From  Tanenbaum's Structured Computer Organization:

> Figure 2-4(a) illustrates **a pipeline** with **five units**, also called
>   stages.
>
> If one pipeline is good, then surely two pipelines are better. One
>   possible design for a **dual pipeline** CPU, based on Fig. 2-4, is
>   shown in Fig. 2-5. Here **a single instruction fetch unit** fetches pairs
>   of instructions together and puts each one into its own pipeline,
>   complete with its own ALU for parallel operation.
>
> A different approach is used on high-end CPUs. The basic idea is to
>   have just **a single pipeline** but give it **multiple functional units**, as
>   shown in Fig. 2-6.  The definition of ‘‘superscalar’’ has evolved
>   somewhat over time. It is now used to describe processors that issue
>   multiple instructions—often four or six—in a single clock cycle. Of
>   course, a superscalar CPU must have multiple functional units to hand
>   all these instructions to. Since superscalar processors generally have
>   one pipeline, they tend to look like Fig. 2-6.

I wonder what counts as a pipeline?

In Figure 2-4(a), a pipeline consists of 5 stages.

In figure 2-5, two pipelines share the same instruction fetch unit, but why isn't it a single pipeline?

In figure 2-6, a pipeline has multiple functional units, but why isn't it multiple pipelines?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 2-4(a) each stage processes one instruction at a time using one unit for every stage. In 2-5 the instruction fetch unit remains the same but fetches *two* instructions that are then processed parallelly, each with its own unit. So we have two pipelines of cause. They are logically and physically seperated. 
But as far as I understand, the main difference between 2-5 and 2-6 is that in 2-6 the CPU decides dynamically what the order of execution of the instructions will be (out-of-order-execution) so that it can eliminate dependencies and hazards. The multipipeline approach executes parallel but in-order. But a superscalar CPU will as well need all stages twice. *I personally* think it would be wrong to say a superscalar has one single pipeline.